# How to set round corner image from bitmap (get image string from server)

Tags: android, bitmap

i have tried this code image rounder perfectly but rounded image can not focus my face!!! any body help me?

```
//Bitmap mbitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cat)).getBitmap();
  Bitmap imageRounded = Bitmap.createBitmap(result.getWidth(), result.getHeight(), result.getConfig());
  Canvas canvas = new Canvas(imageRounded);
  Paint mpaint = new Paint();
  mpaint.setAntiAlias(true);
  mpaint.setShader(new BitmapShader(result, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
  canvas.drawRoundRect((new RectF(0, 0, 258, 250)), 120, 120, mpaint);// Round Image Corner 100 100 100 10

  // ivPhoto.setImageBitmap(result);
  ivPhoto.setImageBitmap(imageRounded);
```

Answer (score 0):

If only a rounded imageview is what you're looking for then a `CircularImageView` might help you, it also supports the `.setimageBitmap()` method

Check this [library](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView). Its pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this library](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView), have many customization's.